# Ruby installation and profile reload

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I've recently installed ruby using this tutorial :

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

However every time I turn off my computer and open terminal. I need to type `. ~/.bash_profile` so I can do `bundle install` or anything else ruby related.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, has anyone encountered similar issue?

Comment: Maybe try adding `source ~/.bash_profile` to `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: As the author of that blog post I can say that I've never seen someone have to do that before. I hope you get an answer that helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what McGar said, you want to make sure that you have 'Run command as a login shell" checked in your terminal window.

For instance, in Fedora 19 (I'm sure it'd be the same in Ubuntu 12.04) go to: Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command, and then check 'Run command as login shell'. I'd also recommend close/open all open terminals after making that change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like following lines in your .bashrc:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

#This loads rvm
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial of enabling login shell => http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal (not copy pasting as instruction on the site might get updated / improved).